# How can a forked node process send data to a terminal or to the parent on exit?

Tags: node.js, signals, ipc, node-cluster

I am dealing with an odd problem which I couldn't find the answer to online, nor through a lot of trial and error.

In a multi-multi process cluster, forked worker processes can run arbitrarily long commands, but the parent process listens for keepalive messages sent by workers, and kills workers that are stuck for longer than X seconds.

Worker processes can asynchronously communicate with the rest of the world (using http, or process.send ipc communication), but on exit, I'd like to be able to communicate some things (typically, queued logs or error details).

Most online documentation for process.on('exit', handler) indicates usage of console.log, however it seems like forked processes don't inherit a normal stdout, and the console.log isn't a direct tty, it's a stream (the ipc stream, I presume?).
Because of this, the process exit handler doesn't let me use console.log to log extra lines (or if it does, I'm not sure where these lines end up)

I tried various combinations of fork options (silent/not silent, non-default stdio options like inherit), using fs.write to write to tty or a real file, using process.send, or  but in no case, was I able to get the on-exit handler to log anywhere visible.

How can I get the forked process to successfully log on exit?

small additional points - all this testing is on unix-like systems (macos , amazon linux...) and both parent and child processes are fired with --sigint-trace so that we can get at least the top 10 stack frames of the interrupted process on exit. These frames do make it out to the terminal successfully

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit of a misunderstanding about how SIGINT is handled, and I believe that it's impossible to accomplish what I want here, but I'd love to hear if someone else found a solution.

- Node has its own SIGINT handler which is "more powerful" than custom SIGINT handlers - typically it interrupts infinite loops, which is extremely useful in the case where code is blocked by long-running operations.
- Node allows one-upping its own SIGINT debugging capabilities by attaching a `--trace-sigint` flag which captures the last frames of execution.

If I understood this correctly, there are 4 cases with different behavior

- No custom handler, event loop blocked

  - process is terminated without any further code execution. (and `--trace-sigint` can give a few stack traces)
- No custom handler, event loop not blocked

  - normal exit flow, process.on('exit') event fires.
- Custom handler, event loop blocked

  - nothing happens until event loop unblocks (if it does), then normal exit flow
- Custom handler, event loop not blocked

  - normal exit flow.

This happens regardless of the way the process is started, and it's not a problem about pipes or exit events - in the case where the event loop is blocked and the native signal handler is in place, the process terminates without any further execution.

It would seem like there is no way to both get a forced process exit during a blocked event loop, AND still get node code to run on the same process after the native interruption to recover more information.

Given this, I believe the best way to recover information from the stuck process is to stream data out of it before it freezes (sounds obvious, but brings a lot of extra considerations in production environments).